# Join Query effects natural ordering

Tags: mysql, php

If we have 2 tables

```
**user**
+----+------+------+-----------+
| id | user | pass | gender_id |
+----+------+------+-----------+
| 1  | lisa | good |     11    |
| 2  | jack | pass |     10    |
| 3  | paul | 5555 |     10    |
| 4  | rich | none |     10    |
+----+------+------+-----------+

**gender**
+----+--------+
| id | gender |
+----+--------+
| 11 | female |
| 10 | male   |
+----+--------+
```

If we join  them like so

```
SELECT user.id, user.user, user.pass, user.gender_id, gender.gender FROM `user` JOIN `gender` on user.gender_id
```

The result of query

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "2"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "jack"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "pass"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "3"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "paul"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "5555"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "4"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "rich"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "none"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "1"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "lisa"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "good"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "female"
    }
```

The order has now changed even though we did not specify this.(user lisa is last)
If we change lisa gender_id to 11, and run the same query, the result will be

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "1"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "lisa"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "good"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "2"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "jack"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "pass"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "3"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "paul"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "5555"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "4"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "rich"
    ["pass"]=>
    string(11) "none"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "male"
    }
```

This result is how the rows are positioned in the table(user lisa first), which is represented correctly in the results as we did not specify any order.

Why is the first result set being ordered when we are not specifying this. It does not seem correct, I want the results to be pulled exactly how they are positioned in the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a relational database, there is no such thing as a "natural order".  If you care about the order of your results, you have one and only one option-- specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Without looking at the query plan, I would guess that your `gender` table is the driving table of a nested loop join which happens to return all the `male` rows first.  It would be perfectly valid, though, for the order of results to change if the optimizer decides to use a different plan, if the underlying data changes, if you add and remove rows over time, etc.  If you care about the order, specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

Adding an `ORDER BY` does not necessarily force the database to do any more work.  It is entirely possible that it simply causes the database to choose a query plan that returns data in the order you want as a side effect.

Comment: Excellent comprehensive answer. The gender is driving the order. Thanks

Comment: If there is no such thing as a "natural order" how would we ORDER BY the position in the database? We couldn't use ID, as if we swap the last row ID with the first, They stay in the same position.

Comment: @cecilli0n - What does "position in the database" mean to you?  The physical order of rows in a heap-organized table is not something you should ever depend on.  If you have some idea of a "natural" order, you would need to have a column in the table that captures that information that allows you to sort the data.

Comment: If we use a tool for example phpmyadmin to view the database, When we swap the last ID with the first ID, The rows stay in the same position, they do not move. (atleast from phpmyadmin point of view.) Unless what you are saying is it must be tool which is deciding this?

Comment: @cecilli0n - I would guess that the tool has some sort of `order_by` column in a table and is ordering by that column or is storing the "correct" order somewhere else.  It's also possible that the tool is relying on some behavior that is not guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: @cecilli0n No, PHPMyAdmin does not use any hidden column nor it affects the order of the rows returned. It's juct coincidence that (the same index is used and) you get the rows in the same order. You never know when a different index (or indexes) will be chosen by the optimizer and the rows will be shown in diferent order.